# Is it possible to search groups based on name using fql?

Tags: facebook-fql

Based on my research, the **name** field from the **group** table is **not indexable**. Only the **gid is**. 
So is it possible to query groups which names contain a particular keyword ("Golf" for instance) just like using the Facebook search bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/ is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate on the answer because I don't see the answer there and I have been trying to do the same thing